# Report that only displays employees directly reporting to the manager running the report

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, datamodel

Hello I'm running Obi 11g and I'm creating a dashboard for managers and I'm having difficulty finding a way to create a report for the dashboard that shows only the employees directly reporting to the manager running the dashboard / report.

I've done a little research and I'm guessing this is going to be done by session variables? but i'm not sure how. If there was a way I can pull the executing user's username I could just say `employee.username = session.username` and then run the query accordingly but is there a way to this?
Any help would be appreciated greatly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for

`SELECT fnd_global.user_name FROM DUAL`

This posts the username instead of the schema.

Answer (score 0):

This is Oracle. It offers a function named `USER` that returns ... well, *current user*. So, your query might utilize it as

```
where employee.username = user
```

Comment: user returns with the value 'FUSION_RUNTIME' no matter who I'm logged into.

Comment: user variable will return schema name.. so hence it returns with the value 'FUSION_RUNTIME' no matter who is logged into. because everyone is using the same schema.

Comment: I see; sorry, I hoped that it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Since this may be an Oracle *product* but not and Oracle *database* query, you will need sth more OBI-specific:

VALUEOF(NQ_SESSION.USER)

Comment: Anyway you can show me an example query? I'm getting an invalid table name for this one.

Comment: Not sure what you mean or what your problem is since you aren't being very precise about it. What I described is standard functionality which exists in exactly this form since almost 20 years.

Comment: I think its more because. I misunderstood exactly what I was trying to say or my research could have been completely wrong and it through people off on my question. I'm writing a SQL query in a data set for a data model. I want to pull the current username of whoever runs the report that uses this data model. I've tried user `sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_USER')` i've also tried SESSION_USER and it all comes back with fusion or fusion_runtime

Comment: "I'm writing a SQL query in a data set for a data model." That's BI Publisher and not OBIEE. While BIP may be integrated, it's still a totally different technology.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry about that I'm still just starting out in Oracle and someone incorrectly(apparently) told me I was in OBIEE. That actually explains a lot of troubles with my searches as well. Thanks for the clarification. I'll remove the obiee tag then.

Comment: The "wrapper" or platform product is OBIEE. But BIP was bundled with OBI about a decade ago and so many people confuse the two / mix them. Doesn't really help when trying to understand issues :)